# Add line to text file based on multiple matches

Tags: awk, sed, insert, match

I am trying to modify a file using sed, awk or other Linux standard commands such that on matching two lines that start with some common character, a line is inserted with some text that shows that the section has ended.

Given contents like:

```
a 2021-08-12 14:42:21.0
b 2021-08-12 14:42:22.0
a 2021-08-12 14:42:22.0
b 2021-08-12 14:42:22.0
b 2021-08-12 14:42:23.0
c 2021-08-12 14:42:54.0
c 2021-08-12 14:42:54.0
a 2021-08-12 14:43:27.0
b 2021-08-12 14:43:27.0
a 2021-08-12 14:43:28.0
b 2021-08-12 14:43:28.0
b 2021-08-12 14:43:28.0
c 2021-08-12 14:43:59.0
c 2021-08-12 14:44:00.0
a 2021-08-12 14:44:33.0
b 2021-08-12 14:44:33.0
c 2021-08-12 14:45:06.0
a 2021-08-12 14:45:39.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:39.0
a 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
c 2021-08-12 14:46:11.0
c 2021-08-12 14:46:11.0
```

I would like to end up with:

```
a 2021-08-12 14:45:39.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:39.0
a 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
c 2021-08-12 14:46:11.0
c 2021-08-12 14:46:11.0
##Some Text##
a 2021-08-12 14:45:39.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:39.0
a 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
c 2021-08-12 14:46:11.0
c 2021-08-12 14:46:11.0
##Some Text##
a 2021-08-12 14:44:33.0
b 2021-08-12 14:44:33.0
c 2021-08-12 14:45:06.0*
a 2021-08-12 14:45:39.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:39.0
a 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
c 2021-08-12 14:46:11.0
c 2021-08-12 14:46:11.0
##Some Text##
```

As you might be able to see, before the last sequence, there is a failed test that has not completed successfully......if this could be handled too, that would be great, the end of one set of data will always be 'c' before the new set of data starts with 'a', if not easily that don't worry, it's not that often to worry about.  In this case there are 7 lines output per iteration of the program, but there could be any number of steps.

I have tried things like:

```
sed '/3 /{p;s/.*/1/;H;g;/^\(\n1\)\{2\}$/s//##TEXT##/p;d}'
sed -z 's/^3/&\n##TEXT##/2'
sed  -e '/^\[3 \]$/,/^\[2 \]/{/^1 .*/a'"##TEXT##" -e '}'
```

I just can't seem to get it to work....find where 2 lines together start with same pattern or character, insert some text after that match.

Any help appreciated!!

Thanks
/G

Comment: I don't really understand the condition for this insertion. Is it two consecutive lines starting with a `c`? And what are these `sed` commands that you show? Why do you search for `3`? I don't understand the relation with your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you asked for (print text after 2 back to back rows that start with `c`):

```
$ awk '{print} ($1=="c") && (p==$1){ print "##Some Text##" } {p=$1}' file
a 2021-08-12 14:42:21.0
b 2021-08-12 14:42:22.0
a 2021-08-12 14:42:22.0
b 2021-08-12 14:42:22.0
b 2021-08-12 14:42:23.0
c 2021-08-12 14:42:54.0
c 2021-08-12 14:42:54.0
##Some Text##
a 2021-08-12 14:43:27.0
b 2021-08-12 14:43:27.0
a 2021-08-12 14:43:28.0
b 2021-08-12 14:43:28.0
b 2021-08-12 14:43:28.0
c 2021-08-12 14:43:59.0
c 2021-08-12 14:44:00.0
##Some Text##
a 2021-08-12 14:44:33.0
b 2021-08-12 14:44:33.0
c 2021-08-12 14:45:06.0
a 2021-08-12 14:45:39.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:39.0
a 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
c 2021-08-12 14:46:11.0
c 2021-08-12 14:46:11.0
##Some Text##
```

but I think this might be what you actually need instead (print text before a row that doesn't start with `c` when the row before it did start with `c`), assuming that the line in your input `c 2021-08-12 14:45:06.0*` is the case you're referring to in "there is a failed test that has not completed successfully......if this could be handled too," and the way you want it handled is to print the same text as the other cases where we print that text:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{txt="##Some Text##"} ($1!=p) && (p=="c"){ print txt } {print; p=$1} END{ print txt }' file
a 2021-08-12 14:42:21.0
b 2021-08-12 14:42:22.0
a 2021-08-12 14:42:22.0
b 2021-08-12 14:42:22.0
b 2021-08-12 14:42:23.0
c 2021-08-12 14:42:54.0
c 2021-08-12 14:42:54.0
##Some Text##
a 2021-08-12 14:43:27.0
b 2021-08-12 14:43:27.0
a 2021-08-12 14:43:28.0
b 2021-08-12 14:43:28.0
b 2021-08-12 14:43:28.0
c 2021-08-12 14:43:59.0
c 2021-08-12 14:44:00.0
##Some Text##
a 2021-08-12 14:44:33.0
b 2021-08-12 14:44:33.0
c 2021-08-12 14:45:06.0
##Some Text##
a 2021-08-12 14:45:39.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:39.0
a 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
c 2021-08-12 14:46:11.0
c 2021-08-12 14:46:11.0
##Some Text##
```

or if you want different text printed in the case of a block that ends in a single `c` instead of 2 `c`s:

```
$ awk '
    ($1!=p) && (p=="c"){ prt() } {print; pp=p; p=$1} END{ prt() }
    function prt() { print (pp==p ? "##Some Text##" : "##Some Other Text##") }
' file
a 2021-08-12 14:42:21.0
b 2021-08-12 14:42:22.0
a 2021-08-12 14:42:22.0
b 2021-08-12 14:42:22.0
b 2021-08-12 14:42:23.0
c 2021-08-12 14:42:54.0
c 2021-08-12 14:42:54.0
##Some Text##
a 2021-08-12 14:43:27.0
b 2021-08-12 14:43:27.0
a 2021-08-12 14:43:28.0
b 2021-08-12 14:43:28.0
b 2021-08-12 14:43:28.0
c 2021-08-12 14:43:59.0
c 2021-08-12 14:44:00.0
##Some Text##
a 2021-08-12 14:44:33.0
b 2021-08-12 14:44:33.0
c 2021-08-12 14:45:06.0
##Some Other Text##
a 2021-08-12 14:45:39.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:39.0
a 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
b 2021-08-12 14:45:40.0
c 2021-08-12 14:46:11.0
c 2021-08-12 14:46:11.0
##Some Text##
```

In the above `p` is just a variable that holds the previous value of $1 and `pp` holds the value of $1 from 2 lines back.

Comment: Perfect!!!
Thanks Ed.
The only thing that would make this better is if a different text could be used for the failed iteration.  However, this perfectly addresses the requirement of thousands of lines of code being reviewed in seconds.

Comment: @GavinHainsworth regarding `The only thing that would make this better is if a different text could be used for the failed iteration.` - that's exactly what the 3rd script in my answer already does, please take another look and note `##Some Other Text##` instead of `##Some Text##` being printed for the failed iteration (assuming I understand what you mean by that).

Comment: Yes Ed, in my excitement at getting some output in the desired format I failed to notice the second one.  I have pretty much digested the first one, the second one introduces some things I have not come across before, but I will get there. Thanks

Comment: Sounds good and to be clear it's probably the 3rd script you want.

Answer (score 0):

The following was tested with GNU `sed` 4.8 and the BSD `sed` version (2005) distributed by Apple with macOS.

As you started with `sed`, here is a `sed` solution. I assume that you want to insert your text after two consecutive lines starting with a `c` (not sure I understood completely your specifications):

```
sed -E '/^c/{x;/^c/a\
##Some Text##
;x;};h' data.txt
```

The final `h` copies each line in the hold space. When a line starts with a `c` (matches `/^c/`) we exchange the pattern space and the hold space and if the latter also starts with a `c` we append the text; of course we exchange back the pattern space and the hold space.

If you prefer a one-line command and your shell is `bash`:

```
sed -E $'/^c/{x;/^c/a\\\n##Some Text##\n;x;};h' data.txt
```

Comment: You should mention that requires GNU sed for `-E`. It MAY work with BSD sed as well but I'm skeptical as almost every sed command that does more than s/old/new/ seems to use some kind of version-specific extension(s). I know you added `--posix` on the last command but that doesn't mean that the command will work in any POSIX sed as it could be relying on undefined behavior which IS defined for GNU, for example `-E` itself is undefined in POSIX.

Comment: I just tried `sed -E $'/^c/{x;/^c/a \##Some Text##\n;x};h' file` with BSD sed (which doesn't support a `--posix` option) and it failed with `sed: 1: "/^c/{x;/^c/a \##Some Te ...": extra characters after \ at the end of a command`. The first version of the script in your answer failed with the same error too.

Comment: Your BSD `sed` is maybe the one found on macOS (2005). It requires a final semi-column in any group, plus its append command requires a newline immediately after `a<backslash>`. I modified my answer such that it also works with this old `sed`.